# In Power Automate, how do I filter a list and save the result?

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to filter a list in Power Automate. I followed the instructions, and it's correct, but it doesn't save the result to my variable and there is no "output" variable for me to save it manually. How do I save the result?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh nevermind; I found the results, it was in the "Body" variable.